# Make SKSpriteNode subclass using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I'm trying to create class which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode and I want to add other properties and functions to it. But in the first step I faced an error.
Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class Ball: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        super.init(imageNamed: "ball")
    }
}
```

It's not a compile error, It's run-time error. It says: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` and `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:)' for class Project.Ball`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It says: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.
And `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:)' for class Project.Ball`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25171066/2158465

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to call the designated initializer for `SKSpriteNode`. I'm actually surprised you didn't get another error about not full implementing `SKSpriteNode`, are you using an older Xcode6 beta maybe?

Since you have to use the designated initializer, you need to call `super.init(texture: '', color: '', size: '')`.

It would be something like this:

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Note:** *I also added the `init` for `NSCoder` which Xcode will require.*

Comment: `SKSpriteNode` has no `init()` initializer, so you shouldn't have `override` in the delcaration.

Comment: Can someone help me and show how this Ball Class gets initialized in another Swift File? I cant get it running :-/

Comment: Color is not nullable on SKSpriteNode's designated initializer, so you need to use `UIColor.clearColor()` when calling super.init

Comment: SKColor.clearColor() works as an alternative to what leolobato wrote. It is a part of the SpriteKit library.

Comment: Latest Xcode (10.0) won't accept nil as color. I had to use .clear instead (based on leolobato's and JKT's comments)

Comment: Sorry @MikeS; edited your answer then rolled back. not sure if you want to keep the code in line with the latest Xcode or not.