# Strange MetaType Initialization Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have this class Minion

```
class GameObject : SKShapeNode {
    var health : Int!
}

class Character : GameObject {
    var cost : Int!
    var movementSpeed : Int!
    var damage : Int!
    var specials : [Special] = []
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class Minion : Character {
    required init() {
        super.init()
        self.cost = 2
        self.movementSpeed = 21
        self.damage = 2
        self.path = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(50, 50)).path
        self.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

If I want to instantiate the MetaType of this class I can do this.

```
let a = Minion.self()
```

with no error or crash.

However... If I try to do this.

```
let b = Minion.self
let ax = b() << NO ERROR BUT CRASHES
```

I receive a BAD_ACCESS_CODE crash.
This crashes as well.

```
let b : Minion.Type = Minion.self
let ax = b()
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you’ve managed to convince the compiler to let you do something you shouldn’t.

If you removed your `GameObject` type from the hierarchy and just had `Character` inherit from `SKShapeNode`, you’d get a compiler error with your `init`:

```
error: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'SKShapeNode'
}
^
SpriteKit.SKShapeNode:109:34: note: 'required' initializer is declared in superclass here
  @objc(initWithCoder:) required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

Yet somehow, by inserting `GameObject` into the middle there with no user-defined `init` method, it’ll let you get away with it at compile time – but not at runtime.

Looks like your problem is similar, though not necessarily the same, to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397672/make-skspritenode-subclass-using-swift) and the same solution may help.