# Xcode sks editor: How to use "custom class"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, sprite-kit, editor

When I am editing a sks scene in the Xcode editor and I highlight a SKSpriteNode there are the fields "Custom Class" and "Module".

[image]

How can I use these fields if a have implemented a Subclass of SKSpritenode?

It does not work if I fill in the class name, for example

Custom Class: "MyCustomBomb"

```
@interface MyCustomBomb : SKSpriteNode
```

EDIT:

```
@implementation MyCustomBomb

-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        SKSpriteNode *image = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];
        [self addChild:image];

        textlabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText@"test text"];
        [self addChild:textlabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  How are you looking for success?

Comment: For example custom behavior does not work, if the implementation is similar to the example i added above, I do not see the additional sprites and labels.

Comment: Doesn't appear that `init` is [the designated initializer for SKSpriteNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164313/swift-must-call-a-designated-initializer-of-the-superclass-skspritenode-error)

Comment: very good advise. Now I call the designated initializer: self = [self initWithTexture:textue color:color size:size]; but it still does not work :(

Comment: Typo?  `self = [super initWith...`  not `self = [self`...

Comment: yes, definitely a typo :S  But it does not work anyhow...

Comment: Oh, but in terms the subclass, it must override the designated initializer of the super. `init` still won't ever get called... I was assuming you'd fixed the method prototype as well.

Comment: mh, it seems my understanding and my programming skills aren't the best^^ Maybe some has a short example code snippet or a link to a tutorial? I'm stuck now :(